# Quickly switching Visual Studio source control agent

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version-control, plugins

This is probably the ultimate in lazy, but is there any way I can change the source control agent used in Visual Studio 2010 without having to go through Tools->Options->Source Control->Plugin?

Ideally I just want a quick button press or somthing like that.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a [custom keyboard shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx).